# Image Classification: Heavily unbalanced data over thousands of classes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I have a dataset consist of around 5000 categories of images, but the number of images of every category varies from 20 to 2000, which is quite unbalanced. Also, the number of images are far from enough to train a model from scratch. I decided to do finetuning on pretrained models, like Inception models.

But I am not sure about how to deal with unbalanced data. There are several possible approaches:

1. Oversampling: Oversample the minority category. But even with aggressive image augmentation technique, we may not be able to deal with overfit.
   Also, how to generate balanced batches from unbalanced dataset over so many categories? Do you have some ideas about this pipeline mechanism with TensorFlow?
2. SMOTE: I think it is not so effective for high dimensional signals like images.
3. Put weight on cross entropy loss in every batch. This might be useful for single batch, but cannot deal with the overall unbalance.

Any ideas about this? Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy` and set weights for each class inversely proportional to their training frequency to "balance" the optimization.

Comment: It is a good idea, I have thought it before. I have about 5000 classes and some classes have more than 2000 image while some only have 20. If I apply this rule to a single batch, some images in minority class will be multiplied by 100, while the batch size is only 20. I think training for other class in this batch will be destroyed. What do you think of this problem?

Comment: I would be very surprised if you can make your model generalize for a class with only 20 training samples. Is there another way you can state your problem? For instance, instead of using 5000 independent labels can you use "mixed" labeling (e.g. class 1 having labels [1 0 ... 0 1 ... 0 1 ] and so on)?

Comment: That's the hard part of this problem. I cannot really generalize my model to some minority classes. Also, I am not expecting a perfect result for my model, an accuracy of 80% would be good. For your idea, I don't see the advantage of using mixing labels, can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: 80% is still a pretty high number given the context. Have you thought about my problem restatement comment?

Comment: Yes, I have thought about that. Do you mean using mixing labels instead of one-hot label? For example, in three classes cases, one hot label would be [1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1]. Using mixing label, it can be like [1 1 0], [0 1 1], [1 0 1]. Any three linearly independent vectors would work. If it goes like this, I cannot figure out how this can help me settle down the dataset's unbalance. Could you please give me a more detailed explain?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the pre-trained ImageNet layers, add your own final layers (with appropriate convolution, drop out and flatten layers as required). Freeze all but last few of the ImageNet layers, then train on your dataset.

For unbalanced data (and in general small datasets), use data augmentation to create more training images. Keras has this functionality built-in: [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try your method on Inception_Resnet_v2. Also, do you have some ideas about handling the unbalance data?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment about the unbalance data. I am trying to use image augmentation to augment the minority class with Augmentor and imgaug library. I will report my result after finishing my model training.

Comment: Also, I oversampled my images from minority classes to compensate the unbalance.

Comment: Hi @TongShen, did you figure it out? Can you please help me out as I am in a similar sttuation as you were.